# php - PHPUnit are showing dots that are in newline

Tags: php, phpunit

I was setting up the unit tests of one of our projects, when I did a test run it show that the dots are all in new line.

[image]

My phpunit.xml configuration is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
      <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
      <exclude>
        <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
      </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
  <php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

The xml was copied from another project with a working phpunit output format.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have multiple files inside ```./tests``` ? Each file prints its output into a new line

Comment: Could you post one of the TestController ?

Comment: can phpunit output the dots in one line?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article the problem could be:

> So after a little research I found out that there was an interface in our application that was closed with a ?> (php close tag) and after that some new lines.

https://coderwall.com/p/zbdluw/newlines-on-phpunit-tests

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found a php close tag in our project but it still did not did the trick.

Comment: In my case, I had a new line before a `<?php` tag